# Is this a proper way to find the frame rate of this GameWindow (OpenTK C#)

Tags: c#, opentk

I just want to make sure that I'm getting the correct frame rate of this game window

Here is my code:

```
       int fpsCounter = 0;

    private void Window_RenderFrame(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        fpsCounter++;
        if (fpsCounter == 60)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(this.RenderFrequency);
            fpsCounter = 0;
        }

        this.SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `fpsCounter` rather a `frameCounter`?

Comment: RenderFrequency contains current FPS value (calculated using only previous render frame time) which is usually not very representative.
It's better to calculate average FPS for a whole second.